# Error with SQLite3 on Python

Tags: python, sqlite

This is my code. When I am trying to run this code. I face following error. Anyone can suggest me how to correct that error and this script can run successfully.

```
from tkinter import *
import sqlite3

global a, b

def sair_mestre ():
    global mestre
    mestre.quit()

def criar_tabela():
    c.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Registro (Nome text, Senha text)")

def receberl():
    global Nome, Senha
    Nome = entradalogin.get()
    Senha = entradasenha.get()
    ler_dados(Senha)
    if x:
        sucesso = Label(mestre, text="Login Realizado com sucesso!")
        sucesso.grid(row=1,column=1)
    else:
        inexistente = Label(mestre, text="Login errado")
        inexistente.grid(row=1, column=1)

def receber2():
    logincadastro2 = entradalogin2.get()
    senhacadastro2 = entradasenha2.get()
    c.execute("INSERT INTO Registro VALUES(?, ?)", (logincadastro2, senhacadastro2))  # Utilização de Variáveis
    conexao.commit()
    cadastro.destroy()

    realizado = Label(mestre, text="Cadastrado com sucesso")
    realizado.grid(row=1, column=1)

    botaorealizado = Button(mestre, text="Ok", command=sair_mestre)
    botaorealizado.grid(row=2, column=1)

def registro():
    programa.destroy()

    global cadastro
    cadastro = Frame(mestre)
    cadastro.grid()

    realizando_cadastro = Label(cadastro, text="Realizando Cadastro...")
    realizando_cadastro.grid(row=0, column=1)

    labellogin = Label(cadastro, text="Login")
    labellogin.grid(row=1, column=0)

    labelsenha = Label(cadastro, text="Senha")
    labelsenha.grid(row=2, column=0)

    global entradalogin2
    entradalogin2 = Entry(cadastro)
    entradalogin2.grid(row=1, column=1)

    global entradasenha2
    entradasenha2 = Entry(cadastro, show="•")
    entradasenha2.grid(row=2, column=1)

    botaocadastro = Button(cadastro, text="Ok", command=receber2)
    botaocadastro.grid(row=3, column=1)

def ler_dados (valorbusca):
    global row
    global x
    buscar_dados = "SELECT * FROM Registro WHERE Nome = ? AND Senha = ?"
    for row in c.execute(buscar_dados, (valorbusca,)):
        if Nome and Senha in row:
            x = True


conexao = sqlite3.connect("Registro_Cadastro.db")
c = conexao.cursor()

criar_tabela()

mestre = Tk()

programa = Frame(mestre)
programa.grid()

login = Label(programa, text="Login")
login.grid(row=0, column=0)

global entradalogin
entradalogin = Entry(programa)
entradalogin.grid(row=0, column=1)

senha = Label(programa, text="Senha")
senha.grid(row=1, column=0)

global entradasenha
entradasenha = Entry(programa, show="•")
entradasenha.grid(row=1, column=1)

botaook = Button(programa, text="Entrar",command= receberl)
botaook.grid(row=2, column=1)

botaoregistro = Button(programa, text="Cadastro",command= registro)
botaoregistro.grid(row=3,column=1)

mestre.mainloop()
```

This is the error thrown by my program. Can anyone help me to resolve this error?
I think the error is in `receberl` function.

```
File "-------", line 1558, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)

File "------", line 17, in receberl
    ler_dados(Senha)

File "------", line 69, in ler_dados
    for row in c.execute(buscar_dados, (valorbusca,)):
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 2, and there are 1 supplied.
```

Answer (score 3):

The error message you are getting is pretty clear: your `SELECT` query binds two parameters, but your code only specifies one of them.  To fix, first change your call to `ler_dados()` to pass in both the username and password:

```
def receberl():
    global Nome, Senha
    Nome = entradalogin.get()
    Senha = entradasenha.get()
    ler_dados(Nome, Senha)
    # ... etc.
```

And then in your query bind both the username and password:

```
def ler_dados(username, valorbusca):
    global row
    global x
    buscar_dados = "SELECT * FROM Registro WHERE Nome = ? AND Senha = ?"
    for row in c.execute(buscar_dados, (username, valorbusca,)):
        if Nome and Senha in row:
            x = True
```

Comment: I made both suggested changes and give this error now: Exception in Tkinter callback Traceback (most recent call last): File "-----", line 1558, in call return self.func(*args) File "-----", line 16, in receberl Nome = entradalogin.get() File "-----", line 2530, in get return self.tk.call(self._w, 'get') _tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".5288976.5207312"

Comment: Your code is full of errors, you should use a debugger.

Comment: Can you give me examples? Pls

Comment: I did, I was destroying the entries before using the .get on them, lol

Answer (score 2):

You need to provide 2 arguments for this query :

```
buscar_dados = "SELECT * FROM Registro WHERE Nome = ? AND Senha = ?"
```

When you call `ler_dados(Senha)` in the function `receberl`, looks like `Nome` is missing.

You should use something like : `ler_dados(Nome, Senha)` first

and then change the method `ler_dados` to :

```
def ler_dados (nome, senha):
    global row
    global x
    buscar_dados = "SELECT * FROM Registro WHERE Nome = ? AND Senha = ?"
    for row in c.execute(buscar_dados, (nome, senha)):
        if Nome and Senha in row:
            x = True
```

Comment: **I made both suggested changes and give this error now:**                                 Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "-----", line 1558, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "-----", line 16, in receberl
    Nome = entradalogin.get()
  File "-----", line 2530, in get
    return self.tk.call(self._w, 'get')
_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".5288976.5207312"